# Static variable initialized with wrong value

Tags: c, static

I've defined a function like this

```
static void
flatten_tree(...)
{
  static int num = 0;
  ...
}
```

However, when the function is executed, `num` gets some random value, rather than 0 on the first run. Upon subsequent function calls it behaves as static var should do. Aren't static variables explicitly initialized with zero? What is the proper way to initialize it?

Comment: how do you know it's not initialized to 0? can you show us?

Comment: What compiler / version?

Comment: @fernando.reyes I'm investigating it with gdb.
`(gdb) b flatten_tree`
`Breakpoint 2 at 0x81cd496`
`Breakpoint 2, flatten_tree (...) at ...`
`(gdb) p num`
`$1 = 7`

Comment: Show more code.  It's possible a pointer on the stack is overwriting the values.

Comment: compiler supposed to initialize all static to 0. Is it always a different random value ?

Comment: I am guessing you are looking that in your GDB when the control is *on* that line, when it's not initialized yet. But actual initialization happens only after you type *next* ;-)

Comment: According to the documentation all static variables has initial default value zero. if you think you're right show us the code.

Comment: it seems that it's properly initialized with zero (http://ideone.com/Bu0vI1) even without explicit initialization  (http://ideone.com/PtNjCX)

Comment: What compiler, what OS, what environnement ?

Comment: Either gdb is very confused or it's not the first call to `flatten_tree` and it keeps the value that was written to it on an earlier call to that function. There's no way I can imagine that this value hasn't been initialized properly long before your code started running without a seriously broken OS/compiler.

Comment: Yes, global variables not explicitly given a value are initialized to 0.

Answer (score 0):

If it's not set to zero the first time it's called then either your C implementation is broken, your debugger is broken, or you've made some other error - I won't comment on which is the most likely scenario :-)

If you *really* want to see what it's doing, chage your code temporarily to something like:

```
static void
flatten_tree(...)
{
  static int num = 0;
  printf( "XYZZY DEBUG: initial num is %d\n", num);
  exit(1);

  ...
}
```